# Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to specified type 'BookingObject!'

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created booking object as follow in swift,

```
import Foundation

class BookingObject {
    var bookingTitle: String = ""
    var bookingDesc: String = ""
}
```

then add data as follow

```
private var bookingData:NSMutableArray?
for country in countryCode  {
    bookingObj.bookingTitle = country.name
    bookingObj.bookingDesc = country.name
    bookingData?.addObject(bookingObj)
}
```

and problem is got following when retrieve value

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    /* error found that line */
    let bookingObj:BookingObject! = bookingData?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    let cell = bookingTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BookCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookCell
    cell.lbAppointmentTitle.text = bookingObj.bookingTitle
    return cell   
}
```

Please let me know what I did wrong to leaked that error

> Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to specified type
>   'BookingObject!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a struct and the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol:

```
struct Booking : CustomStringConvertible {
    let title : String
    var description : String { return title }
}
```

Declare the `bookings` property like this:

```
private var bookings : [BookingObject] = []
```

Add items like this:

```
for country in countryCode {
    bookings(Booking(title: country.name))
}
```

Get your items like this:

```
let booking = bookings[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

Kametrixom's answer will work, and is what you should do in its entirety. Your specific problem is the declaration of the array, which should be `[BookingObject]`. You need the other changes because the class object has reference semantics, and you only ever have one of them.